# How can I read a full sequence of digits using tesseract instead of first digit only

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I have the following clear binary image, and I want to read the digits using `tesseract`.
[image]

**My problem** is that `tesseract` is reading only the first digit (**5**)!

How can I make `tesseract` read the full sequence?

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

gray = cv2.imread('input.jpg', 0)

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, config='outputbase digits')

print(text)
```

> Output: 5 < o x o c >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do some amount of preprocessing before you push the image directly to `pytesseract` for extraction of text. One thing that comes to mind is using `binary_fill_holes` to fill the area inside edges. Here is an example of what you can do.

```
from skimage import io, util, feature
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

#Import image
img = io.imread('jbAsM.jpg', as_gray=True)

#Preprocessing
imginv = util.invert(img)  #Invert image

#Loop and fill holes iteratively
for i in range(2):
    edges = feature.canny(imginv) #find edges
    imginv = ndi.binary_fill_holes(edges) #fill holes in edges

fill_inv = util.invert(imginv)  #invert again
plt.imshow(fill_inv, cmap='gray') 

#Image to text
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(fill_inv, config='outputbase digits')
print('Extracted Text ->',text)
```

[image]

```
Extracted Text -> 5113
```

**EDIT:** No idea why `pytesseract` is predicting the last digit as 3 (weird!!)

You will have to find your own preprocessing pipeline that suits the other images. I would recommend looking at `image segmentation` and `edge filling methods`.